# Upload large file to s3 with php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

How can i change the default value 2MB of **upload_max_filesize** to 6MB  in amazon aws where application is hosted so that i can upload larger file than the default value in S3 bucket. ?

Comment: There is no Default value for S3 you can upload a single file of 5Gb to S3. To increase the upload limit you have to do that in PHP.INI file by changing the value for upload_max_filesize

Comment: My problem is how to change this value in php.ini, i can do it in local server, but my application is hosted in amazon aws, i can read the php setting in aws but i don't know how to change upload_max_filesize in aws server ?

Comment: R u using Ubuntu or AWS Linux?

Comment: 64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09

Comment: Ok check if you have a php.ini file at this path /etc/php.ini

Comment: `upload_max_size` in php applies only to files/data being sent TO php. it has no effect whatsoever on stuff that php's sending OUT.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to have terminal access to your EC2 with either one of the method listed in AWS manual:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstances.html

Then, browse to the file location which your phpinfo() shows, for example: /etc/php.ini, edit the file with:

```
vi /etc/php.ini
```

Search for the text: upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, follow the instruction as listed in [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

Make a page with the following php code

`phpinfo();`

[image]

There you are going to see the location for the php.ini

and set the value `upload_max_filesize` to wahtever you want

Comment: i open the phpinfo() page of aws and i see what  you show me, but i still can't find the location to  make the setting, sorry for that, i'm not good at that point...

Comment: up to now i can see the default value of upload_max_filesize is readonly...

Comment: please don't let me go

Comment: my problem now is  to reach the location so that i make the setting

Comment: do you have access to the cli(console)? what is the location?

Comment: where can i access the cli(console), is it on the amazon server side ?

Comment: hmmm you let me go